# Joomla 1.5 user group questions

Tags: joomla

Does it affect the way joomla authenticate users if I add a custom user groups in the *Joomla 1.5.15* and does it make it less secure?

I'm planning to add a custom group using the table `jos_core_acl_aro_groups` as described at http://docs.joomla.org/Custom_user_groups.

But someone told me that if I add a new user group and the group_id is greater than 25 (this is the ID of the Super Administrator), that new group will have the same access as the super admin in the default joomla core files without changing anything just the additional user group. Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have a local instsall of Joomla to try this?

Anyways, it's not true because it can't be, why should the group_id define the access rights? That would be a terrible ACL implementation. But please try it, before you actually use it live.

In Joomla 1.5 you can make user groups but they will have one of the existing role patterns. In Joomla 1.6 (alpha) there will be full flexibility in defining your groups, roles and granular ownership settings for each article, module, etc.

Comment: hi tharkun, yes i have installed joomla on my localhost and i'm working on it. I successfully created a new group and all newly registered users are assigned to that group. I don't know how to test if this new users has the same privilidges as the admin.

I tried loging in on the administrator panel but it says its not allowed. Is there another way to test this?

thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

There are several extension you can find at:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security

Which enhance the core ACL functions.  Give them a look and you'll probably find the solution without hacking the core files.